# Permissions to certain groups and users?

Tags: python, django, authentication

In my project, the user can login into my application. I have two groups in my project. When User gets login into my application, I am able to recognize, the user is in which group. Now My problem is I need to denied the access to few users based on groups(example: User1 is of Group1, user1 has a accesss for viewapi1,viewapi2, etc.... and User2 is of group2, user2 has a access for viewapi8,viewapi9,etc.....). My Problem is from When the user knows the url he can access it, so please say me how to denied permissions for user if he is not given access to that url/API.
I am not good in API's and new to this. Please help me how to do.

Comment: You can use exempt urls in the settings.py. This will provide access to only certain webpages if the user has not authenticated. For example: 

`LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS = (r'^/logout/$',r'^/help/$',)`

Comment: @LewisHepburn I'm afraid I don't see how this is supposed to solve the OP's problem ?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers apologies, I've missed quite a bit off. Sai, I used [This Link](https://python-programming.com/recipes/django-require-authentication-pages/) to help create Login Middleware to handle the authentication for the pages. It reduces the amount of decorators for all your views that require authorizing if your working on a large project .

Comment: @LewisHepburn I still fail to see how this answers the OP's problem...

Answer (score 1):

This is [fully documented here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/auth/default/#limiting-access-to-logged-in-users-that-pass-a-test). You can either just use the `user_passes_test` decorator and test the user's groups in your callback, or - better but a bit more involved - assign relevant permissions to your groups and use the `permission_required` decorator.

Comment: The link is not getting opened. Thank you.